# (Ubuntu 23.04) Various Steam games shut down immediately on launch

Tags: wine, games, steam

I'm very new to Linux in general, and have been trying to troubleshoot issues running some of the games and programs I liked using while in Windows in order to learn more about it. I was struggling getting Wine to run with a specific program, and  uninstalled something important that caused games that used Vulkan to crash. I have since fixed that error but certain issues are still persisting. One of the games I play now requires the use of protontricks(Deep Rock Galactic, requires vcrun2019) in order to properly run, unsure why. Other games on my Steam act wildly different. Some  don't launch at all, others launch perfectly. It appears games that use run into launchers won't work at all anymore either.

My Ubuntu version is 23.04 and my desktop is KDE Plasma, with screen animations turned off. I have two dump logs that I've gotten from games that are having the first issue. Are there any obvious pointers I can use in order to run these games? Am I missing any further dependencies? I've attached images below, feel free to ask me anything if you need it. Thank you.

[End of first game's crash dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3FS3.png)

[End of second game's crash dump. harder to decipher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dw9s.png)

Comment: Have you tried running the games with Proton and let Steam handle all the configuration and dependencies? Have you tried different versions of Proton? What graphics and driver version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried different versions of Proton and they all seem to close the same way. I am using an RTX 3080 on the driver version 535.104.05, the most recent to the best of my knowledge. I just realized I completely forgot to mention that I have been running all these through Proton. Sorry for the confusion. I've tried Proton 8.03, 7, 5, and the Proton GE versions. Thank you!

Comment: I have recently downgraded from the 535 to the 525 driver because I had similar issues after an update. Might be worth a try.

Comment: I was able to downgrade to 525, though my external monitors weren't being detected for some reason. After reinstalling the drivers I was able to see them and try again. Sadly, it didn't seem to help. Are there any .dlls or packages I may need to reinstall? Do I need to install dxvk or should that already come with my distro(its missing from my list, which is why I'm interested)?

Comment: Normally Steam installs everything it needs on first installation (except maybe when you're using the snap version, I wouldn't recommend that), and then Proton pulls all the necessary dependencies into a separate sandboxed environment per game. I never had to install any packages system-wide manually to get a game running. You can try forcing the games to run without Vulkan though using `PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%` as a launch option, if it's a problem with Vulkan compatibility (which it often is).

Comment: @Sebastian Sorry for not getting back to you yesterday. I tried using that command and didn't notice anything different. Steam seems to just be doing the same thing. I'm able to run games in both OpenGL and Vulkan while on an emulator like PCSX2 or DuckStation, so maybe its just a steam/proton thing? I'm not sure.

Comment: Gonna go ahead and close this one, I sort of fixed it? I must have messed my OS up severely when I was playing around in it. I have reinstalled Ubuntu on my system and my issues appear to have been mostly resolved. I've learned to be more careful when tinkering with applications. Thank you for your help, Sebastian!